# How to send 2 kind of values from the ng-model

Tags: angularjs

How to send 2 kind of values in the ng-model?
I want to send this values

`ng-model="ctrl.nuevoEnlace.odus_enlaces_ne[0].ftx"` or `ng-model="odu.ftx"`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9G9W.png)

[image]

Comment: Please never post images of code, especially when said images are behind some link that is likely to expire any time soon. Instead post the code in the question and use code formatting as instructed.

Comment: this is my 1st time using StackOverflow sorry for that.

Comment: One of the first things we do when examining code for errors is to try compiling (if necessary) and running the code to see what happens. We may also copy part of the code to paste into search engines in order to learn about the types or algorithms we are using, and to find other similar questions. When we are provided an image of code, this process becomes much more difficult.

Comment: Edit the question. Remove the images containing code from it. Copy and paste our code into the question. It is very important that the code is the minimum needed to reproduce our problem, and that it is well formatted. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20640802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-change

```
<input ng-model="firstValue" ng-change="secodValue=firstValue">
```